# Is there a way to hide some modules of the project view in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

For example, is there a way to the project view just show the `appcenter` module and hide the others from the view.

[image]

Comment: You can consider moving these modules into subfolder and keep it collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Answer for Android Studio 4.2.2, not tested with previous versions)**

Maybe Android Studio **Scopes** may do the trick.

1. Open *File* menu > *Settings*
2. Navigate to "*Appearance & Behavior*" > *Scopes*
3. Create a scope with "+" button, give it a name, and select in the tree the relevant part you want to show. Nodes can be include or excluded in a single way or recursively.
4. When done, valid and close the dialog with Ok.
5. On top of the "*Project*" tool window, click the dropdown button to show all the available views (*Project*, *Packages*, ...) Here, the scope you've just created should be listed and can be selected.

The project tree should only show the scope configured items.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks :)